# Remove warning BC42108 during rebuild

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

This is the first bit of my VB.NET code:

```
Private Function CreateEventMWB(pWeek As XmlNode, sEventSettings As GoogleEventSettings, strEventType As String, ByRef rbCreated As Boolean) As My_GoogleEvent
    Dim sEvent As My_GoogleEvent

    sEvent.strTitle = pWeek.Attributes(kEventTitle).Value()
    sEvent.strDate = pWeek.Attributes(kDate).Value()
    sEvent.strTime = pWeek.Attributes(kStartTime).Value()
    sEvent.strLocation = GetXmlNodeText(pWeek, kSpecialEventLocation)
    sEvent.iMeetingDuration = 105 ' 1h 45m
    sEvent.bSpecialEvent = GetXmlNodeBoolean(pWeek, kSpecialEvent)
    sEvent.bNoMeeting = GetXmlNodeBoolean(pWeek, kNoMeeting)
    sEvent.bFirstWeekOfMonth = GetXmlNodeBoolean(pWeek, kFirstWeek)
    sEvent.strTag1 = strEventType
    sEvent.strTag2 = ""
    sEvent.strEventDetails = ""

    rbCreated = False
    If (Not sEvent.bNoMeeting) Then
        ' It does not matter if this is a special event (like a circuit visit meeting)
        ' as it is still a meeting
        rbCreated = True
    ElseIf (Not sEventSettings.bExcludeSpecialEvents) Then
        ' We already know there is no meeting for this date.
        ' Therefore it is going to be a special event. But are we including special events? - Yes!
        rbCreated = True
    End If

    If (rbCreated) Then
        ' We have one of two scenariors
        ' 1. It is a normal meeting or a special meeting
        ' 2. It is a special event (if they were not excluded)
        Dim bCreateAsMeeting = True

        If (sEvent.bSpecialEvent And sEvent.bNoMeeting) Then
            bCreateAsMeeting = False
        End If

        If (bCreateAsMeeting) Then
            AddToEventDetails(sEvent, "IDS_TPL_MWB_GOOGLE_NOTE", sEventSettings.dictLabels, GetXmlNodeText(pWeek, kNote))
```

The variable **sEvent** gets correctly filled. The program works - always has done. But the last call in the code `AddToEventDetails` raises a **warning** when I compile:

[image: Warning]

I am not sure exactly how I can prevent the warning.

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder why this works because you never initialize `sEvent`. The first line should be `Dim sEvent As New My_GoogleEvent()`. You should get a `NullReferenceException` at runtime

Comment: ...`New` being the missing element.  Without it, there is no instance and should crash when you try to assign to it